# Spring - bean access in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, javabeans

I have configured a bean like this and I have forum.host.url in the file properly

```
<bean id="forum_host_url" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="forum.host.url"/>
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I need to access this bean value from a JSP, I have tried

```
${forum_host_url}
```

in my jsp file but its not getting any value. what is the correct way?

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `InternalResourceViewResolver` you can do something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <list><value>forum_host_url</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If you prefer, you can use `exposeContextBeansAsAttributes` property and JSPs will be able to access all your beans.